# Take difference between variables to create new variable unless they match

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
test <- data.frame('cost'= c(120, 3, 2, 4, 10, 110, 200, 43, 1, 51, 22, 14),
               'price' = c(120, 20, 10, 4, 3, 4, 30, 43, 56, 88, 75, 44)
                )
test

    > test
   cost price
1   120   120
2     3    20
3     2    10
4     4     4
5    10     3
6   110     4
7   200    30
8    43    43
9     1    56
10   51    88
11   22    75
12   14    44
```

I am trying to create a new variable that takes the difference between the two columns unless they match and if they match then it would return the value that both columns have.

```
Desired:
   cost price NewVar
1   120   120   120
2     3    20   -17
3     2    10   -8
4     4     4    4
5    10     3    7
6   110     4   106
7   200    30   170
8    43    43    43
9     1    56   -55
10   51    88   -37
11   22    75   -53
12   14    44   -30
```

This is what I tried but it gave me an error that I was missing a TRUE/FALSE argument or something like that.

```
test <- test %>%
        mutate(NewVar = if(cost==price) cost else cost - price)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` as `if/else` is not vectorized and expects a vector of length 1.  Here, the number of rows are greater than 1, so use the vectorized `ifelse` or `if_else` (from `dplyr` which also checks the `type`) or `case_when`

```
test$NewVar <- with(test, ifelse(cost == price, price, cost - price))
test$NewVar
#[1] 120 -17  -8   4   7 106 170  43 -55 -37 -53 -30
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
     mutate(NewVar = ifelse(cost == price, price, cost - price))
```

or with `case_when`

```
test %>%
     mutate(NewVar = case_when(cost == price ~ price,
                      TRUE ~ cost -price))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for your time! I have a quick question when reading "~" in your mind how do you think of this?

Comment: @KreitzGigs  Thanks.  I guess it comes with practice that using  a particular function would expect a particular output.